# Question about Northwind DB example

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3

When messing with the Subsonic 3.0 Northwind stuff:

```
var product = Product.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == 1);
```

I found the following was possible, but not workable) using intellisense:

```
var product = Product.SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderDetails == 1);
```

OrderDetails as a member of Product, is an IQueryable.  I guess I'm new to LINQ, but I was wondering how to use this member?  Everytime I try to get info out of this I get an error.  Could someone give me an example of how to use the OrderDetails member of Product?  And perhaps throw the results in a databind to a Gridview?

Look at the following code and tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
 var products = from od in OrderDetail.All()
                   join p in Product.All() on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                   select od;
```

I get the following error:

```
Object of type 'System.Single' cannot be converted to type 'System.Decimal'.
```

Comment: What's the error you receive?

Comment: It's not that I'm getting a particular error.  I just want any example of how to use the Product's OrderDetails member.

For example if you say:

    Product x = new Product();

What can be done with x.OrderDetails?  For example, can I use this to display all of the order details of products with a product id of 1?

Answer (score 1):

The IQueriable members that are exposed by SubSonic are your Foreign Keys.  You could use them in the following manner.

```
 Product.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == 1).OrderDetails.ToList()
```